# How to keep some part of the Canvas NOT Touchable

Tags: java, android, touch, android-canvas, draw

All i need to do is to create a canvas with some non-touchable Section.
I tried with an overlay (Relative layout) over the canvas at desired place. But Canvas is still touchable. I have no clue why this is happening.

Can anybody tell me how can i make some part of Canvas is not touchable.

Answer (score 2):

if logical solution required,

Just catch touch event, >> find location of event,

If Location is within non-touchable area, return false, else true.

I think this will help. :)